# Interpretation of mathematical object, which is based on the definition of the Lie algebra $\text{so}(1,1)$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, lie-algebras

Consider a mathematical object
$$g=\bigg\{\text{2 $\times$ 2 matrices Y $\bigg|$}~ e^{tY}\in G ~\forall t \bigg\},$$

where $\text{Y}=\exp\big(X\big),$ and $X={\displaystyle  {\begin{bmatrix}0&a\\a&0\end{bmatrix}} }.$

If you replace $Y$ with $X$ in the definition then you get, $\text{so}(1,1)$ which is a [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Lie_algebra). And in this case $G$ would be $\text{SO(1,1}).$

> How should one understand $g?$ Does it relate to $\text{so}(1,1)?$ What can one say about $G?$

I know that $Y\in \text{SO(1,1)}.$ But I don't know how to interpret $G$ because one is taking the matrix exponential of an element of $\text{SO(1,1})$ multiplied by parameter $t.$

Comment: Wait, so you want $Y\in SO(1,1)$ **and** $e^{tY}\in SO^\ast(1,1)$ for all $t$? The latter is equivalent to $Y\in\mathfrak{so}(1,1)$. Thus, it seems you're trying to find $SO(1,1)\cap\mathfrak{so}(1,1)$, which is simply $\big\{[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}]\big\}$.

Comment: @runway44 I didn't realize $SO^*(1,1)$ was already notation for something. I edited the post